# Windows login screen loop

Tags: windows, login, infinite-loop

So I recently installed software like ux-style, classic shell, 7ztaskbartweaker an rain Meter just to make my laptop look cooler but then I ran into problem that when I shut down my laptop and start if I login it brings be back to log in its basically a login loop BUT :

If I restart my computer from the option then it lets me log in so someone suggested me to clean boot the Pc and now I can't even log into my laptop even after the restart method no way if I restart or shutdown it still does the login loop for ever !!!

Logon loop details: I press enter than put my pass code/password(tried both) and it shows welcome then it shows me a blqck screen for a few seconds then a white screen for a fraction of second than back to the login screen to enter pass code

NOTE: It turns of num lock and caps lock when it brings me back to the logon screen!

It works for people wondering there are two options one which I selected as my answer in for my question other one

My way: Login in safe mode you can search it up online and once you are in safe boot open the classic shell menu it has a option when you click shutdown then the computer will hybrid shut down instead of shut down turn off that option so your computer shuts down normally and your computer works fine back again also when you are in safe mode turn the clean boot setting back to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Windows on a USB drive or CD, you can re-install it. This won't wipe your computer. Simply, you'll have some settings reset so that booting your operating system and using your operating system work properly. Everything else should be the same.

If you have the CD, that will be very easy. If not, use another machine to put your version of Windows onto a USB drive as an ISO. Then, you'll want to go into your BIOS and make sure that that USB drive boots before your already-installed operating system. At some point, you'll want to check your machine for a sticker that has your key to verify that you legally own your copy of Windows, and you'll enter this key before it will let you install the operating system if that's your situation.

[Instructions for creating a USB with Windows OS ISO](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/9585/how-to-setup-a-usb-flash-drive-to-install-windows-7/)

A restore point could be used to revert back to a previously-saved image, or another option is that you can re-image the machine. If you have a standard desktop configuration image saved onto a drive or CD, that will be used to wipe everything and re-install your operating system with pre-defined settings, files, and applications. It is not recommended to re-image a machine too many times. It really takes a toll on hard drives.

Comment: Well for now I  have just managed to fairly make it back to normal just by changing a setting in the classic shell in the safe boot mode and it works completely fine although thanks for your idea if anything like this happens and nothing works out I can use that probably!. Although I see a windows sticker on my thing I can't seem the find the windows key my laptop is Lenovo Ideapad Y700 15 inch touch screen with gtx 960m

Comment: You can also find your key in regedit.exe under "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" type REG_BINARY named "DigitalProductId".